# Merge Join in SSIS package using composite key

Tags: ssis, merge, primary-key

Is it possible to use 'Merge Join' transform to join to tables using same composite key (with full outer join)? I have browsed a bit but could not see any reasonable response.

My requirements are like below,
Table 1: Column A, B and C with A,B are primary keys
Table 2: Column A, B and D with A,B are primary keys

Destination table: A, B (both primary keys), C and D.

Most of the examples I saw was using a single primary key.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You Must use Sort Key positions from 1 to n .

[image: Here 2 means second primary key]